# How I can move wrap line of the code in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, android-studio-3.6.1

How I can move to left or right this wrap line? I am using Android Studio 3.6.1.

The problem is that if I have long text and I use `Reformat Code with dartfmt` the code move to the next line because of that line and is hardly readable in the flutter app at least to me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution in Android Studio / Preferences / Editor / Code Style / Dart: (it was 80 by default)
 [image]